# How send mail from SQL Server after fulfilling a date condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to send an email from SQL Server upon fulfilling a condition of dates which is to send a mail after one hour of the DATE_FIN

The table is the following:

```
SELECT [ID_EVENTO]
,[FIRST NAME]
,[OBJECTIVE]
,[START DATE]
,[END DATE]
,[ID_LUGAR]
FROM [Events]. [Dbo]. [TBL_EVENTO]
```

First I thought about doing this with a trigger but it has been getting more complicated ...

What do you advise me?

Comment: Have you thought of using a SQL Job that runs through checking your dates/times and having that do what you need on a schedule? Or is this more on an immediate type thing, like after an INSERT?

Comment: It is after an INSERT, when saving the record in the Events table, the mail is sent one hour after the END_DATE

Comment: Sending emails from a trigger is often a bad idea. I agree that an Agent Job sounds like the right idea here. *Also, a trigger occurs on an event like a DML or DDL statement. A trigger won't fire because "a value" in a table is the same value as the current date and time; which appears to be the behaviour you're after.*

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the insert, it has everything to do with END_DATE and the current system time. A trigger is 100% the wrong tool here. You should look at a sql job and scheduling it. I would also advise you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In your case @SebastianSalazar, I would use a job that runs every 5, 10, 15 minutes--whatever you need--that checks for that one hour window and then sends the email. You could have a look at SERVICE BROKER too, however, that's more involved than what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the trigger but I need that with the end_date increase 1 and send mail

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[enviarCorreo]
    ON [dbo].[TBL_EVENTO]
    AFTER INSERT
AS

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @profile_name = 'Pruebas',
   @recipients = 'pruebacorreo@correo.com',
   @body = 'Prueba mail',
   @subject = 'Prueba correo' ;
```

Comment: I don't see where you are checking for any kind of duration here, Sebastian. Are you checking for the expired hour somewhere else then updating the record in the table to fire this trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have a DB job scheduled that runs, say, every minute or whatever frequency you think is better for your requirements. This job will check if one hour has elapsed from END_DATE value, and will trigger the email.

HTH!

Comment: How is this more of an answer than the three nearly identical comments? There is enough detail in the question that you could actually demonstrate the query. Then this would become a viable answer.